# How do i deal with 'to' must be of length 1 error?

Tags: r, syntax-error, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to use GA algorithm for calculating shortest distance between clients,

Below is my Code

```
file1<-read.xlsx("distance_matrix_v1.xlsx",sheetName = "Sheet1",header = T)
str(file1)
file1$Place<-as.character(file1$Place)
newdf<- file1 %>% column_to_rownames("Place")
str(newdf)
class(newdf)

D2 <- as.matrix(newdf)
D2


#Function to calculate tour length 
    tourLength <- function(tour, distMatrix) {
    tour <- c(tour, tour[1])
     route <- embed(tour, 2)[,2:1]
    sum(distMatrix[route])
      } 

#Firness function to be maximized

tspFitness <- function(tour, ...) 1/tourLength(tour, ...)

 GA <- ga(type = "permutation", fitness = tspFitness, distMatrix = D2,
     min = 1, max = attr(newdf, "Size"), popSize = 50, maxiter = 5000,
     run = 500, pmutation = 0.2)  


summary(GA)
```

This is my Matrix

```
> D2
       A  B  C  D  E  F  G H  I
    A  0 10  2  2  8  1 17 8  6
    B 10  0  8  8  1  7  9 2  2
    C  2  8  0  1 11  2 17 8  7
    D  2  8  1  0  9  8 17 8  8
    E  8  1 11  9  0  4 10 1  2
    F  1  7  2  8  4  0 12 4  3
    G 17  9 17 17 10 12  0 9 10
    H  8  2  8  8  1  4  9 0  2
    I  6  2  7  8  2  3 10 2  0
```

the error occurs in this part

> GA <- ga(type = "permutation", fitness = tspFitness, distMatrix = D2,
>   +          min = 1, max = attr(newdf, "Size"), popSize = 50, maxiter = 5000,
>   +          run = 500, pmutation = 0.2)
>   Error in seq.int(lower, upper) : 'to' must be of length 1
>   In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: In ga(type = "permutation", fitness = tspFitness, distMatrix = D2,  :
>     'min' arg is deprecated. Use 'lower' instead.
>   2: In ga(type = "permutation", fitness = tspFitness, distMatrix = D2,  :
>     'max' arg is deprecated. Use 'upper' instead.

Comment: HI, what do you get when you just run `attr(newdf, "Size")`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I have changed the max value to my number of drop points and it worked.[example- max = 10]